# Express problem: "," is expected, but when it's added, the error still shows

Tags: node.js, json, express

I'm still very new to coding and I'm currently exploring Express. I get this problem "," while I have tried to add it as instructed, it still shows :(

```
const express = require("express"); const fs = require("fs")
 
const app = express();
 
const PORT = 3000;

app.get('/products', (req, res) => {
     fs.readFile('./masterdata/products.json', (err, data) => {
         if(err){
             res.status(400).json({
                 message: "Something wrong when loading the data"
             })
             res.status(200).json(JSON.parse(data))
             // res.json([
             //     "Apple",
             //     "redmi",
             //     "One plus"
             // ])
 
         }
     } }),
 
 app.get('/orders', (req, res) => {
     res.json([
         {
             id: 1, 
             paid: false, 
             user_id: 1
         },
         {
             id: 2, 
             paid: true, 
             user_id: 2
         }
     ]) 
 })
 
 app.listen(PORT, () => {
 console.log(`Server Listening on port ${PORT}`); })
```

and the error message that I receive is ***(',' expected.)***

Please help me to figure it out. Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: Please format the code correctly (use code formatting, not quote formatting) and tell which line throws the error.

Answer (score 0):

I formatted your code and got this:

```js
app.get('/products', (req, res) => { 
    fs.readFile('./masterdata/products.json', (err, data) => { 
        if(err){ 
            res.status(400).json({ message: "Something wrong when loading the data" }) 
            res.status(200).json(JSON.parse(data))
        }  
    }
})
```

With this, I received the same error you did. But you are missing a `)`

```js
app.get('/products', (req, res) => { 
    fs.readFile('./masterdata/products.json', (err, data) => { 
        if(err){
            res.status(400).json({ message: "Something wrong when loading the data" }) 
            res.status(200).json(JSON.parse(data))
        }
    }) // Added paren to close readFile
})
```

Note, you probably want your `res.status(200)` outside of the `if` block

```js
app.get('/products', (req, res) => { 
fs.readFile('./masterdata/products.json', (err, data) => { 
    if(err){
        res.status(400).json({ message: "Something wrong when loading the data" })
    } else {
        res.status(200).json(JSON.parse(data))
    }
  })
})
```